# when occured user sleep state in mysql processlist

Tags: php, mysql

i found [User sleep] state query in my db(mariadb).
mysql document say "The thread has invoked a SLEEP() call."

this means applicaton call the sleep?
my web server use php.

Answer (score 0):

`User sleep` means a query is currently running that uses the [`SLEEP()`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/sleep/) miscellaneous function.

Examine the full text of the query that is running for that thread using `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;`.